# ScrollView in a popup appearing at the bottom and too small?

Tags: python, layout, kivy

I am trying to add a ScrollView to a popup in kivy but the scroll view only seems to be taking up a small portion of the popup and down the bottom for some reason.

The only thing I can think to do is to set the height of the scroll view explicitly but I don't know how to do this because it needs to scale with the window size and the popup.height seems to include the header bar.

Here is my code:

```
scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None))
popup = Popup(title='Thanks Stack Overflow!', size_hint=(0.9, 0.9), content=scroll)
box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(1, None))
scroll.add_widget(box)
box.bind(minimum_height=box.setter('height'))
for i in range(1000):
        box.add_widget(Button(text='test button {}'.format(i), size_hint=(1, None)))
```

and this is the result I get:
[image: Result from above code]

It is scrollable and works fine it is just that it doesn't take up the correct space.

EDIT: So for now I am setting the height manually to be with respect to the popup size as it seems like the popup title doesn't change too much. But I would still like a better method if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my updated python code file

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import runTouchApp

scroll = ScrollView()
popup = Popup(title='Thanks Stack Overflow!', size_hint=(0.9, 0.9), content=scroll)
grid = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint=(1, None))
scroll.add_widget(grid)
grid.bind(minimum_height=grid.setter('height'))
for i in range(1000):
        grid.add_widget(Button(text='test button {}'.format(i), size_hint=(1, None)))

box = BoxLayout()
box.add_widget(popup)
runTouchApp(box)
```

I removed the `size_hint(1, None)` for the ScrollView. Now they are the default value (1,1). Furthermore it always makes sense to use GridLayout with ScrollView and not BoxLayout. BoxLayout just takes the size of its parent. You need something bigger than its parent, so that it is scrollable.

Sidenote: Take a look at kivy files, I think they make it a lot easier.

Also, I would have set the height of the Buttons. I don't know where they get the height if you don't set them. I did not add that, since I wanted to keep my solution as close as possible to your code.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. I thought you had to set a size_hint to None for the scroll view to actually work but apparently not